# Action of upper triangular matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, group-actions, vector-spaces

Let $M,N$ be two $n\times m$ matrices with $n\leq m$ and coefficients in an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero $K$, both of full rank $n$.

Do there exist two upper triangular matrices $A\in SL(n)$ and $B\in SL(m)$ such that $A\cdot M \cdot B^{T} = \lambda N$ for $\lambda\in K\setminus\{0\}$ ?

Comment: What is the ground field?

Comment: An algebraically closed field of characteristic zero

Comment: If $m=n$, clearly it's true if and only if they have the same determinant.

Comment: Sorry, the question was not precisely stated. I am looking at matrices modulo multiplication by non-zero scalars.

Comment: Then @Ycor has answered your question :)

Comment: Anyway for $m<n$ it's true with no restriction. I think it rather belongs on MathSE.

Comment: Still it is not so clear to me. Have you taken into account that $A$ and $B$ are upper triangular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is negative. Consider for instance
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad N = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Assume that there exist 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
0 & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\ 
0 & b_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$ and such that
$$A\cdot M\cdot B^{T} = N$$
Then
$$A\cdot B^{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{12} & a_{12}b_{22}\\ 
a_{22}b_{12} & a_{22}b_{22}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and hence either $a_{22} = 0$ or $b_{22}=0$ which contradict $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$.

More generally, your action stabilizes the locus of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12}\\ 
m_{21} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I've corrected the product display. Btw even with the relaxed conditions (no condition on determinant and up to scalar $\lambda$) there is no solution: upper right and lower left corners nonzero and lower right zero cannot simultaneously happen.

Comment: Sure, you are right.